# I want to show the data in another page

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to take the id, name image and content of tinymce editor which i want to show on another page using controller. I am using array through which i want to take id, name, image and content but i don't know how to retrive it on another controller.

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="settinglabel">Name</label>
                <input type="text" maxlength="20" class="form-control" ng-model="data.name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" style="margin-bottom: 4px;">
            <div class="BoardCardWithCustomProperties BoardCardWithCustomProperties--hover" draggable="true">
                <div class="BoardCardWithCustomProperties-contents">
                    <img class="BoardCardCoverImage" ng-src={{data.thumbnail}}>
                    <div class="BoardCardWithCustomProperties-nameAndDropdownButton">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="design-9">
            <div class="col-sm-12" style="margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:5px">
                <textarea rows="20" cols="100" ui-tinymce="tinymceOptions" ng-model="tinymceModel" />
                <input name="image" type="file" id="upload" class="hidden" onchange="">
            </div>
        </div>

myApp.controller('SampleFormatCntrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'orderProcessService', '$timeout', 'authService', '$routeParams', 'localStorageService', '$q', 'CommonhttpService', function ($scope, $http, orderProcessService, $timeout, authService, $routeParams, localStorageService, $q, CommonhttpService) {

    var id = $routeParams.id;
    $scope.data = localStorageService.get("formatdata");
    $scope.action = $routeParams.action;
        if ($scope.action == 'Edit' || $scope.action == 'Copy') {
            $scope.action = "Update"
        }
        else {
           $scope.action = "Save"
    }

    $scope.tinyArray = [];
    $scope.screenshot = function () {
        $scope.tinyArray.push($routeScope.tinyArray);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-repeat="elem in data">
  <button id="{{elem.id}}" ng-click="showItem($index, elem)">
      {{elem.name}}
  </button>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.showItem = function(elementIndex, dataItem){
  console.log(elementIndex);    // 0
  console.log(dataItem.id + ':' + dataItem.name);    // 1:Abhishek
}
```